# how to get the keys of array as heading

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Here is my array from the loop

```
(
    [Size] => Array
        (
            [07601-01] => S,
            [07601-02] => M,
            [07601-03] => L,
            [07601-04] => XL,
            [07601-05] => XXL,
        )

    [other] => Array
        (
            [07601-01] => S,
            [07601-02] => M,
            [07601-03] => L,
            [07601-04] => XL,
            [07601-05] => XXL,
        )

)
```

Here is my loop

```
<?php 
     foreach($product_atttribute as $attr) { 
?>
```

**Size**

1. S
2. M
3. XL

**other**
.....etc

```
<?php 
  } 
?>
```

In the above loop how can I get the `Size`, `other`, etc as the heading like below

Comment: `foreach($product_atttribute as $key => $attr)` now you have in `key` Size and other in the loop

Comment: Also a self-duplicator that OP is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21379063/367456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
    'Size' => array
        (
            '07601-01' => 'S',
            '07601-02' => 'M',
            '07601-03' => 'L',
            '07601-04' => 'XL',
            '07601-05' => 'XXL',
        ),

    'other' => array
        (
            '07601-01' => 'S',
            '07601-02' => 'M',
            '07601-03' => 'L',
            '07601-04' => 'XL',
            '07601-05' => 'XXL',
        )

);

foreach( $arr as $key => $value ) {
    echo '<strong>', $key, '</strong><br/>';
    $num = 1;
    foreach( $value as $size ) {
        echo ' ', $num++, '. ',  $size, '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Size
 1. S
 2. M
 3. L
 4. XL
 5. XXL
other
 1. S
 2. M
 3. L
 4. XL
 5. XXL
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($product_attribute as $key => $value) { }
```

Comment: As the other answer suggests, to render the header of the table use `array_keys` to extract just the keys.

Answer (score 2):

use `array_keys` to retrive all keys of passed array if you need it